# Incoming email trigger creation of a TFS work item?

Tags: tfs

In TFS, we have alerts set up to send emails for specific events for work items.

Is there a feature or way to have an incoming email trigger creation of a work item?

This would help to log reported bugs coming from other groups in our organization.

If there's no built-in TFS feature, how could a custom component be built to accommodate this requirement?

Answer (score 6):

TFS does not have this capability built in. Please see this MSDN Forum [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/tfsgeneral/thread/A6710589-EE4F-44A6-9C0B-9F552276EBC4) to have some ideas how this can be done.

> You could write a little service which
> connects/listen to a POP3/IMAP mail
> account and downloads the mails. Go
> through the mail which needs to have a
> specific structure or an attachement
> with the information needed by the
> work item. Then use the Work Item
> Extensibility API and create a new
> work item.
>
> I can imagine a second
> solution. Configure your Sharepoint to
> receive incoming mails. Route them
> into a document list or something and
> let a workflow call the WIT API.

In 2010, the [TFS Work Item Tracking Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is what you need to interact with the TFS server to create new work items.

Answer (score 0):

We use gmail and setup a 'Zap' using zapier.com.  An email that comes into a particular folder in gmail is picked up by the zap and creates a bug in TFS for us automatically.